# Getting error when calling db data from show view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

to easy answer that is pissing me off.

I'm getting this error:
for undefined method `intro' for #

My Model:

about model

```
    belongs_to :user
```

User model

```
    has_many :abouts
```

user controller

```
   def show

       @user = User.find(params[:id])
       @about = @user.abouts
```

user show view

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<h2 class="page-header">Introduction</h2>

<p> <%= @about.intro %> <br></p>
```

Comment: what's the rest of the error after the `#`? I assume it's because @user.abouts is returning an array of About objects, so calling info on them doesn't make sense. you need to iterate through them to get the info out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `User` `has_many` `About` objects, so `@user.abouts` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object type. This object *is not* an `About` object – instead, it's a collection of `About` objects that can be iterated through to access each constituent member. Try the following:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @abouts = @user.abouts
end

# app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% @abouts.each do |about| %>
    <p> <%= about.intro %> <br></p>
    <p> <%= about.cost %> <br></p>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**:

If – as the OP is suggesting in the [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3546549) – only a single `About` record should be returned from a `User`, then it's better to place this logic within the controller than in the view:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @abouts = @user.abouts.first
end

# app/views/users/show.html.erb
<p> <%= @about.intro %> <br></p>
<p> <%= @about.cost %> <br></p>
```

Comment: Please do. If the answer correctly addresses your question, please consider upvoting/accepting it as correct.

Comment: @LeslyRevenge, I've responded to your edit. Does the proposed code address your question?